# "Negative time" when trying to run WAR generated with tomcat7-maven-plugin:exec-war-only

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I generate executable war with `tomcat7-maven-plugin:exec-war-only`. Plugin configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <warFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
        <mode>both</mode>
        <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then `tomcat7:run-war` deploys application and it runs perfectly well.
If I run `mvn package` application jar is created. If I then run `java -jar app.jar` it is successfully deployed with Tomcat 7.0.37. But then it cannot compile any JSP.
It says:

```
2013-09-21 00:38:05 JstlView [DEBUG] Forwarding to resource [/jsp/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
Sep 21, 2013 12:38:05 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 21, 2013 12:38:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
        at java.io.File.setLastModified(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:376)
```

As you see I have no spaces or special characters in JSP name. I also tried to put app.jar to the root of the drive to exclude any possible characters in folder name. Effect is just the same.

UPD. I used remote debugging to see what happens. And the line `Long jspLastModified = ctxt.getLastModified(ctxt.getJspFile());` returns `-1`. In it `ctxt.getJspFile()` returns `"/jsp/login.jsp"`.

Comment: Is it a duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583853/negative-time-from-jsp-compiler ?

Comment: The exception is the same but the cause is not. That problem was connected to special characters in filename and was fixed in Tomcat 7.0.27. I have no special characters and have Tomcat 7.0.37.

Comment: Just a quick question: would you by any chance live in a time zone east of UTC?

Comment: Yes I'm in UTC+4. Why does it matter?

Comment: Rationale: wondering whether your issue is related [this JDK enhancement request](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=f7219a21944824ffffffffa69fb399d8ae43e?bug_id=6791812) : if the deployed JSP file has for some reason a time stamp corresponding to something that's negative wrt epoch (so, have a look at the deployed file's timestamp) you could get this error.  Just execute `File.getLastModified()` on the affected JSP and see what it returns.

Comment: Actual `login.jsp` in the `.extract` directory has the date in this year as it should be. But I used remote debug to see what is happening and... See question update.

Comment: try to set the date of last modification within your project's files. for example "find . -exec touch {} \;" works fine for linux

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why the problem occurs, but found out the solution. The error occurs, because one or more file that you are trying to build, has a negative time. (`file.getLastModified()` returns a negative value). If it's a huge project, might be hard to track which of them has gone wrong. Below code might help:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class ModifyAll {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        File folder = new File("D:/Rakhu/Copy/projectfolder/src");
        FileVO baseFileVO = segregateFiles(folder);
        fileList.addAll(baseFileVO.getFileList());
        folderList.addAll(baseFileVO.getFolderList());

        for (int i = 0; i < folderList.size(); i++) {
            FileVO thisVO = segregateFiles(folderList.get(i));
            fileList.addAll(thisVO.getFileList());
            folderList.addAll(thisVO.getFolderList());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            Date dte = new Date();
            long milliSeconds = dte.getTime();
            System.out.println("Setting Time For " + fileList.get(i) + " as " + milliSeconds);
            fileList.get(i).setLastModified(milliSeconds);
        }
        System.out.println("Succesfully Modified..!!!");
    }

    public static FileVO segregateFiles(File folder) {
        List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                fileList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
            } else {
                folderList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i]);
        }
        return new FileVO(fileList, folderList);
    }
}



FileVO.java
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileVO {
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FileVO(List<File> fileList, List<File> folderList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
        this.folderList = folderList;
    }

    public List<File> getFileList() {
        return fileList;
    }

    public void setFileList(List<File> fileList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    public List<File> getFolderList() {
        return folderList;
    }

    public void setFolderList(List<File> folderList) {
        this.folderList = folderList;
    }
}
```