# Getting error on java web application [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have developed a web application using hibernate framework with MYSQL database and following configurations and geeting following error.
This is working after restarting tomcat server.
This is the content only there are...

```
    error.xhtml
    index.xhtml
    result.jsp

    hibernate.cfg.xml

    pdr
        AccActivate.java
        AccountBean.java
    pdr.config
        Config.java
    pdr.entity
        AccountDAO.java
        CustomerAccountDAO.java
        CustomerDAO.java
        NfcAccountDAO.java
    pdr.entity.sql    
        DuplicateEntry.java
        SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java
    pdr.pojo
        Account.java
        Customer.java
        CustomerAccount.hbm
        CustomerAccount.java
        NfcAccount.java
        account.hbm
        customer.hbm
        nfc_account.hbm
    pdr.util
        ExceptionFiner.java
        HibernateUtil.java
    pdr.util.logger
        Log.java
        MyHtmlFormatter.java
        MyHtmlFormatterExample.java
        MyLogger.java
        MyTestLogger.java
        UseLogger.java
```

### Tomcat:

***Using CATALINA_BASE:***   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65

***Using CATALINA_HOME:***   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65

***Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:*** /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/temp

***Using JRE_HOME:***        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/

***Using CLASSPATH:***       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

***Server version:*** Apache Tomcat/7.0.65

***Server built:***   Oct 9 2015 08:36:58 UTC

***Server number:***  7.0.65.0

***OS Name:***        Linux

***OS Version:***     2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64

***Architecture:***   amd64

***JVM Version:***    1.8.0_65-b17

***JVM Vendor:***     Oracle Corporation

### MYSQL:

***Server version***   5.1.73 Protocol

***version***         10 Connection Localhost via UNIX socket UNIX

***socket***          /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

### Java:

***javac version***      1.8.0_65

***java version***       1.8.0_65

***-*** Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)

***-*** Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

### OS

***Distributor ID:*** RedHatEnterpriseServer

***Release:***        6.7

### System Variables

echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/

echo $PATH

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65//bin:

```
Dec 22, 2015 5:41:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at java.io.File.setLastModified(File.java:1427)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 22, 2015 5:41:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what s there inside File.java:1427(Line number) . it will give IllegalArgumentException .

Comment: There is no file called File.java. I have listed above all files inside ...      Please refer the link https://www.akaza.lk/promotions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is this: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp`.

You have indicated that are using:

> Using JRE_HOME: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/

Tomcat need to compile jsp files into servlets, so the JDK and **JAVA_HOME** is needed. It seems you are using a JDK but instead defined **JRE_HOME**.

Ensure you are using JDK and not only JRE and set **JAVA_HOME** properly.

Comment: I have added my $JAVA_HOME and $PATH variables. please check. I thought that is not the issue. This is working fine first time, second time and more.. But suddenly errors occurred.

Comment: Ok. Did you check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583853/negative-time-from-jsp-compiler)? It seems related to your problem ...

Comment: Thank you, @malaguna I'll check.