# WSO2 application server 5.3.0: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time error when deploying app as ROOT context

Tags: jsp, web-applications, wso2, wso2-as

When  I try to run a simple test war file as the ROOT context of WSO2 Application Server version 5.3.0, I get the following error:

> [2016-03-19 17:24:00,177] ERROR
>   {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/] threw exception [Unable to
>   compile class for JSP] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time     at
>   java.io.File.setLastModified(File.java:1421)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:377)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.statistics.webapp.RequestIntercepterValve.invoke(RequestIntercepterValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bam.webapp.stat.publisher.WebAppStatisticPublisherValve.invoke(WebAppStatisticPublisherValve.java:104)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If I run the same application as any other context path e.g. /testurl it works perfectly. So what could be causing the above Negative time error only when trying to run it as ROOT?

PS: To run my app as root I did two things:

1. moved all other apps out of the webapps directory and renamed my
       war to ROOT.war
2. In ./repository/conf/carbon.xml I set
       WebContextRoot to `<WebContextRoot>/carbon</WebContextRoot>`so now
       the default carbon management app is available on /carbon path.
       (which works perfectly btw.)

This test app has only one single index.jsp file with following content:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test headers</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.println("request.getServerName()="+request.getServerName()+"</br>");
    String[] serverurl= request.getServerName().split("\\.");   
    String clientcode=serverurl[0];
    out.println("clientcode="+clientcode+"</br>");

    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        String value = request.getHeader(key);
        out.println(key+"="+value+"</br>");
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I have seen this [Negative time from JSP compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583853/negative-time-from-jsp-compiler) and it is not applicable in my case. There are no spaces, periods or hyphen characters anywhere in paths of my test war.
It could be caused by `trailing slash in application context` but if it is, I can't figure out what could be causing it.

How do I solve this Negative time problem?

Comment: Can you share the war? I can give a try

Comment: NegativeTime comes most probably due some error in webapp name

Comment: I have put the war on File Dropper here: http://www.filedropper.com/root_1

Comment: I;ll check that later and get back to you

Comment: Seems bug. can you create JIRA in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS

Comment: Added a JIRA here: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-2209